# Upgrade to Angular 17 having issues with SSR

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular17

I update my Angular 14 to Angular 17 and there were some issues. I tried and fixed all of those and most of it was config issues and scss import issues. I have fixed it all and was able to run this locally without SSR.
I wanted to implement SSR and created server.ts, main.server.ts,
app.config.server.ts etc and then updated the config files as well.

I was trying to implement SSR and had this error on UI.

```
Unexpected token ':'
    at new AsyncFunction (<anonymous>)
    at instantiateModule (file:///Users/rohith/Documents/Rohith/GIT/grocery/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28
```

Here are few errors in console as well.

```
▲ [WARNING] You probably don't mean to use the color value blue in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as blue, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $variant'. [plugin angular-sass]

    src/app/styles/mat-button-variants.scss:43:12:
      43 │     &.mat-#{$variant} {
         ╵             ^


  The plugin "angular-sass" was triggered by this import

    angular:styles/global:styles:5:8:
      5 │ @import 'src/app/styles/theme.scss';
        ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any help is appreciated. The relevant file code is below.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "17.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "17.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "17.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "17.0.4",
    "@angular/ssr": "17.0.3",
    "@auth0/auth0-angular": "2.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.4.2",
    "@sentry/angular": "7.81.1",
    "@sentry/angular-ivy": "7.81.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "2.2.0",
    "angularx-qrcode": "16.0.2",
    "auth0-lock": "12.3.1",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "jwt-decode": "4.0.0",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "ngx-editor": "16.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "17.0.0",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "13.0.0",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "8.1.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "17.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "18.0.0",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "17.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.0.4",
    "@types/auth0-lock": "11.27.9",
    "@types/express": "4.17.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "5.1.4",
    "@types/node": "20.9.4",
    "@types/qrcode": "1.5.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.12.0",
    "eslint": "8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "5.1.1",
    "karma": "6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "prettier": "3.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/.well-known",
              {
                "glob": "_redirects",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/app/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/app/styles"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "3mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "myApp:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "myApp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "myApp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "myApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/app/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

More than happy to provide any other part of the code as well.

Comment: Did you update node? What version are you running

Comment: lts/Hydrogen (18.18.2)

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repetition of the tag information plus the single word *issue*, which is meaningless. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is scrolling through a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on how to write a good title, see [ask]. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Updated. Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I was not able to fix this. I am still trying from my end.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to import custom styles into the component's styles, and I found a solution that helped. In the `angular.json` file, you specify `stylePreprocessorOptions` where `includePaths` is the path to your styles as the root path from which all style files will be exported.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": ["src/assets/scss"]
},
```

After that, you import the styles, excluding this path from the import line.

```
@import "utils/variables";
```

Before, I always imported them like this:

```
@import "src/assets/scss/utils/variables.scss";
```